# nginx prepare set_proxy_header for php $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']

Tags: php, nginx

In nginx, how can you set up your `proxy_pass` so it sends to correct client remote ip address? Currently, only the server's ip shows up. I know that the proper way to do this is

```
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
```

However, on the other end I have a support system that is not written by me. I don't want to change all the code to fit the `X-Forwarded-For` parameter.

How can I tell nginx to send the `$remote_addr` in the format so that it can be read with `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`?

Comment: Which server software is running as a backend? If it's apache try installing mod_rpaf.

Comment: On the proxy server it's nginx, the other server where the support system is installed is only a hosted web space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`proxy_set_header REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;` don't work in nginx proxy_pass ([link](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,6760))

So you must prepare some middleware to your application.
For example, pseudo-code:

```
class RemoteAddrMiddleware(request)
    def process_request(request):
       if request['REMOTE_ADDR'].blank?
           request['REMOTE_ADDR'] = request['X-Forwarded-For']
       end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you proxy to an apache 2.4 server, you can use the module [mod_remoteip](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_remoteip.html). It will "translate" the header X-Forwarded-For to a Remote-Addr header thanks to these directives, here an example:

```
#### Set that the Remote IP comes from the header X-Forwared-for
RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
#### Trust the proxy at localhost
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 127.0.0.1
#### Trust the proxy with the address range from 192.168.15.0 to 192.168.15.255
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 192.168.15.0/24
```

Answer (score 0):

In apache 2.2 you can also use libapache2-mod-rpaf.